# Padding MYSQL data with missing dates when comparing year over year stats?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table that tracks emails sent.  It is pretty simple.

ID | DATETIME | E-MAIL | SUBJECT | MESSAGE

I have been collecting data for several years.  Some days I don't have any entries in the table.

query1:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM emails
WHERE DATE(datetime) >= 'XXXX-XX-XX'
AND DATE(datetime) is <= 'ZZZZ-ZZ-ZZ'
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
```

I then use a some php to get one year prior for both XXXX and YYYY and run the second query which is the same as the first...

query2:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) from emails
WHERE DATE(datetime) >= 'XXXX-XX-XX'
AND DATE(datetime) is <= 'ZZZZ-ZZ-ZZ'
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
```

I am using a charting package to compare how many emails I got for a date range and then I overlay how many emails I got for the same range only one year prior.  This is two queries right now and I chart the results.

The issue is where mysql does not have any emails for 2011 for a day in question, but has a few in 2012 for the same day.

Combining the results and graphing them skews the results since I am missing a date and a 0 value for last year for that day, effectively making all my values no longer match up.

```
2011-03-01 10    2012-03-01 4
2011-03-02 4     2012-03-02 2
2011-03-03 6     2012-03-04 1  <---- see where the two queries
                               end up diverging? (I had nothing
                               logged for 2012-03-03 so naturally
                               it was not in the results.
```

Is there a way I can get mysql to output the data I need including dates where value appear in one year but not another OR if no values appear in either year (still need date and 0) so my chart works?

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this...

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `between` clause in query? `select count(ID) from emails where date(datetime) BETWEEN 'XXXX-XX-XX' and 'ZZZZ-ZZ-ZZ' group by date(datetime)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways to get the results for a contiguous set of dates. My favourite one is to create the full set that is required using a dummy table or an existing contiguous set of ids from an AI PK. Something like this -

```
SELECT '2011-01-01' + INTERVAL (id -1) DAY
FROM dummy
WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 365
```

This will return a full set of days for 2011 which can then be LEFT JOINed to your emails table to get the counts -

```
SELECT `dates`.`date`, COUNT(emails.id)
FROM (
    SELECT '2011-01-01' + INTERVAL (id - 1) DAY AS `date`, '2011-01-01 23:59:59' + INTERVAL (id - 1) DAY AS `end_of_day`
    FROM dummy
    WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 365
) `dates`
LEFT JOIN emails
    ON `emails`.`datetime` BETWEEN `dates`.`date` AND `dates`.`end_of_day`
GROUP BY `dates`.`date`
```

To populate your dummy / seq table you can insert the first ten values manually and then use INSERT ... SELECT to add the rest -

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
SET @tmp := (SELECT MAX(id) FROM dummy) + 1;
INSERT INTO dummy
SELECT @tmp + id
FROM dummy;
```

You need to execute the SET query before each run of the INSERT ... SELECT query.

Comment: So i need to create the 'dummy' table and populate it with ID | DATE cols then insert every date for a few years ago and into a few years in the future? Or is this 'dummy' table some kind of temp table that I am not understanding...

Comment: I do have a `seq(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)` table in most of my databases that contains a contiguous set of ids from 0 to 9999 (sometimes larger) as it is useful for doing this sort of thing. Note that it only contains a single integer field which can then be manipulated into all sorts of things when needed, such as dates in this case.

Comment: ah... ok.  I will make a dummy table and throw 9999 records in it and try your suggestion.  Thanks. What is the best syntax to use pure MYSQL to loop and insert 9999 records into that dummy table?  I can do it php but there must be a nice clean 'while' statement that would work.

Comment: I normally insert the first ten records manually and then use INSERT ... SELECT type statements to populate the rest of the table.

Comment: I ran the same query with a test emails table with 500k rows and it returns in 0.04s. Do you have an index on the emails.datetime field?

Comment: "is it ever slow" is near impossible to answer. If the number of emails for the given time period is very large and the amount of memory available is small then it will become slow.